# How to concisely describe your field when your work is very interdisciplinary?

Tags: communication, titles, multidisciplinary

I am a PhD student struggling to identify myself as belonging to a specific discipline. I am always having to introduce myself but never know what to say or write. Any ideas??

The context is often in social situations, where we go around the table and briefly describe our backgrounds.  The particular issue at the moment is writing a bio where we are asked to use the style: 'Julia, Human Geographer.'

I am studying epistemic justice in the context of climate change. I look at historical injustices as well as present day knowledge / power dynamics, considering also cultural and linguistic context. I look at the ways in which climate policies and interventions affect local communities. I work using critical theory, decolonial, feminist and post qualitative theories and methodologies that combine ethnographic and creative methods.

The work seems to sit within science and technology studies, environmental social science, sociology, human geography...but I don't know how to introduce myself when everyone else says 'I'm a biologist, I'm a geomorphologist, I'm an anthropologist' etc. I technically work for a department of international development, but my work has nothing to do with international development, and my home country's nomenclature probably does not map to the rest of the world.

Can anyone help me find a title fit??

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. I moved some info from the comments to the main post (feel free to make further edits if I botched anything). Also, we try to phrase questions in such a way that future readers who have the same problem could potentially benefit from this post, so I rephrased things a bit along those lines as well.

Comment: Thank you - will do my best on the next post : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some general principles for choosing a title for your subject:

1. The title should have at most three words (one word or two words is even better).
2. The words in the title should be common words whose meaning is understood by anyone.
3. The title should not seek to give a full description, or even a completely correct description, of what you study.

In view of these principles, I would say that “environmental social scientist” and “international development researcher” both seem to me to be pretty good titles to use. You can also look at journal titles for journals people who work in your area publish in for inspiration.

If asked for a longer description of what you do, avoid highly abstract formulations that may be very meaningful to you but come across as word salad when interpreted by the average listener. For example, I (a reasonable proxy for an average listener) have no idea what to make of “I am studying epistemic justice in the context of climate change.” Try to ground the description in concrete things, e.g., “I am studying the effects of [some policy] on [some group of people].”

Comment: THanks a lot Dan, that's really helpful!